# Will goals be disallowed if striker's foot is in a dangerous position?

Tags: rules, football

Was having a doubt when I came across this video recently. [Edison Cavani Amazing Disallowed Goal vs. Barcelona](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-2_2-oXmYRE). The goal was ruled out for offside. But suppose there was no offside and Cavani tried this overhead kick. As we can see from the video the defender was trying to clear the ball, and Cavani's striking foot was dangerously close to the defender's head. And maybe even made contact. So question is will this goal be disallowed because of dangerous play if Cavani had actually scored and there was no offside. And if it did, is it fair to the striker who was just trying to make contact with the ball ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A goal like that can indeed be disallowed for playing in a dangerous manner.

According to [Law 12](https://www.theifab.com/laws/chapter/32/section/93/):

> Playing in a dangerous manner
>
> Playing in a dangerous manner is any action that, while trying to play
> the ball, threatens injury to someone (including the player themself)
> and includes preventing a nearby opponent from playing the ball for
> fear of injury.
>
> A scissors or bicycle kick is permissible provided that it is not
> dangerous to an opponent.

With the defender that close to the ball this situation is dangerous enough to disallow the goal and award an indirect free kick to the defending team.